# Rotating a Image based on Mouse X co-ord

Tags: java, rotation, mouseevent, slick2d

I have been trying to find the answer to this question, but cant quite get what I need. Using Slick 2D btw/

I want the java screen to mouse grab when it starts to run, no issue there, but then i need a central sprite to rotate based on mouse moving left and right.

For example. I have:

```
Input input = gc.getInput(); 
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A)) 
    { 
        arrow.rotate(-0.2f * delta); 
    }
```

But instead if the Input.KEY_A i need something like mouse_left

I hope this makes sense!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the actual problem?  Are you getting errors?  Is the rotating not working at all?  Please provide some more context as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Of Course. There is no problem with the rotation. I can make it do that, but I want the mouse to control rotation. Every example I have found only involves making a sprite "look" at the mouse cursor. I dont want it too look at the cursor, but rotate based on the mouse X increase or decrease

Answer (score 1):

You can try to read the mouse position first:

`Point mousePos = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();`

It will give you the location on scree.
And then compare `mousePos.x` with the target's (The component on which you are drawing:)

`Point targetLoc = targetComponent.getLocationOnScreen()`.

If `mousePos.x < targetLoc.x` then the mouse is in left comparing to the target's location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think I made myself clear, so apologies! I meant mouseMoveLeft, not button.

Comment: Only issue is, the targetComp.getLocationOnScreen() is giving me an error. Add cast to targetComp?

Comment: targetComp is actually a subclass of `JComponent` e.g., `JPanel` on which you are drawing. I am guessing that you are painting your image to (0, 0) location using `g.drawImage()` inside the `paintComponent()` function.

Comment: actually using Slick 2d, so the g.drawImage is in the render() function. and its being drawn to getwidth /2 and getheight /2 (the centre of the screen)

Comment: then you don't have to use `targetComponent.getLocationOnScreen()` at all. just `targetX = getWidth()/2`, and `targetY = getHeight()/2` and then compare with mouse location.

Comment: so, I found an easier way of doing this, based loosly on what you said:           if (xpos >= screenx /2) {
   arrow.rotate(+0.2f * delta);
  } the only issue is, that i want the sprite only to move when the mouse is moving? at the minute, if the mouse is still the sprite still moves? I hope that make sense, but i am lot further on that I was!! Thanks for your help so far